# Loop cut and slide using python script in blender

Tags: python, scripting, mesh, add-on

I have created a cylinder using python API of blender. This cylinder has only vertical strips. I want horizontal loop cuts in this cylinder so that it would have a perfect mesh shape of quads. How to do that using python script?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, the way it is done is:

```
old_type = bpy.context.area.type
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'

bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":10, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'ROOT', "edge_index":1})
bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":10, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'ROOT', "edge_index":0})
bpy.context.area.type = old_type
```

So you should be in edit mode, and VIEW_3D context, then use the loop cut to cut the edge "edge_index"

Answer (score 0):

`crt-r` should get you your horizontal cuts then use `shift-Tab` to snap the movement to grid. Doing this you can try and get your prefect quads

Comment: I want to do it by using python script

Comment: this might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OePNW34-z4