# Blender creates screenshot using python script but not when running in background

Tags: python, scripting

*This question is just a [stackoverflow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937262/blender-creates-screenshot-using-python-script-but-not-when-running-in-backgroun) since I've just figured a specific Blender Stack Exchange was existing ! Thanks for your help.*

Am I crazy or is there some bug with this feature (using python script with blender running in background) ?

1/ Copy / paste the following code (from screenshot.py) inside Blender (switch to Scripting view) and it will take a screenshot but ...

2/ Call this script from command line : (so you can automatize screenshots while you're modifying the scene with your script(s) ... for your blog, a tutorial, etc.)

`blender --background --python screenshot.py`

And it will crash without giving informations about what is "incorrect" in the context

**screenshot.py** :

```
import os, sys

#FIXME: Blender creates screenshot using python but not when running in background
#
# Same result from Ubuntu stock version (2.76) and from ppa (2.78)
#
# Within Blender : unable to fix this last warning but screenshot is generated !
#
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "/usr/share/blender/2.78/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_text.py", line 32, in draw
#    text = st.text
#AttributeError: 'SpaceView3D' object has no attribute 'text'
#
# From command line (crash) : blender --background --python screenshot.py
# Unable to determine what's wrong in the context
#
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#(...)
#File "/usr/share/blender/2.78/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 187, in __call__
#    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
#RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.screen.screenshot.poll() failed, context is incorrect

def screenshot(P_filename, P_path = None):
  import bpy

  L_saveAs = P_filename
  L_saveAs = os.path.join(P_path, L_saveAs) if P_path else os.path.join("/tmp", L_saveAs)
  print("Scene saved in " + L_saveAs)

  #XXX: switching to 3D full view = maximize scene in main window
  #bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens['3D View Full']
  for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    print("Window : " + str(window.width) + "x" + str(window.height) + ":" + str(window.x) + "," + str(window.y))
    print("Screen : " + str(screen.name) + ", Scene : " + str(screen.scene.name))
    #for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    for area in screen.areas:
      print("Area   : " + str(area.type))
      if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces:
          print("Space  : " + str(space.type))
          if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            #space.viewport_shade = 'RENDERED'
            for region in area.regions:
              print("Region  : " + str(region.type))
              if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                L_altBpyCtx = {                        # defining alternative context (allowing modifications without altering real one)
                  'area'      : area                   # our 3D View (first found)
                , 'blend_data': bpy.context.blend_data # just to suppress PyContext warning, doesn't seem to have any effect
                #, 'edit_text' : bpy.context.edit_text  # just to suppress PyContext warning, doesn't seem to have any effect
                , 'region'    : None                   # just to suppress PyContext warning, doesn't seem to have any effect
                #, 'scene'     : bpy.context.scene
                , 'scene'     : screen.scene
                , 'space'     : space
                , 'screen'    : window.screen
                #, 'window'    : bpy.context.window     # current window, could also copy context
                , 'window'    : window                 # current window, could also copy context
                }
                bpy.ops.screen.screenshot(L_altBpyCtx, filepath = L_saveAs, full = False)
                break #XXX: limit to the window of the 3D View
            break #XXX: limit to the corresponding space (3D View)
        break #XXX: limit to the first 3D View (area)

screenshot("screenshot.png", ".")
```

3/ By the way, call it without the `--background` argument and it will generate an empty screenshot (size of your window, full of default color, gray in my case). In the meantime, uncomment

`#bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens['3D View Full']`

and/or

`#space.viewport_shade = 'RENDERED'`

And you'll see your Blender interface being affected (switching layout of your views from 'Default' to '3D Full View' and/or your viewport shading from 'Solid', by default, to 'Rendered') ... so the script is actually interpreted but it does not generate the screenshot !

No matter what, the problem seems coming from calling Blender with "--python somescript.py" directly from the command line

I'm probably missing something ?! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the answer from a Blender guy (thanks sergey). Bottom line : **it's a limitation since all the scripts passed via command line argument are executed at command line processing time, prior to any OpenGL draw is done** !

> The warning is caused by script trying to trick the system and
>   override the context, that context is likely in inconsistent state.
>   When running screenshot from the interface you don't need to override
>   any of the contexts.
>
> All the scripts passed via command line argument are executed at
>   command line processing time, prior to any OpenGL draw is done. The
>   screenshot operator itself is just reading OpenGL buffer,m without
>   doing any actual drawing (it can't draw anything since that'd be
>   unsafe).
>
> When running blender in background mode, there is no window created,
>   which also means there is no OpenGL context. You can;t use screenshot
>   in such configuration.
>
> So thanks for the report, but it's just limitation which can not be
>   easily bypassed.

**Precision** : (since the provided code do not show all the attempts made trying to "trick" Blender)

Sadly, if you are also / still interested in such feature, you'll have to think outside (Blender) box ! Don't waste your time trying to "trick" Blender, like delaying script execution, playing with application handlers, faking script import in a Text editor, etc. ... I've done it for you : it doesn't work, probably for a very similar reason.

Comment: surely that's the reason to have bg mode, not to have the UI overhead.

Comment: Yep, but do not help when you're trying to take a _lot_ of screenshots of that UI (multiview, multiaxis, step-by-step) in a 3D printing context (programmatic modeling). Since this limitation is not only affecting bg mode but _all_ scripts launched from command line

Comment: @AnotherTuxUser But how come it doesn't work when we don't use bg mode?