# Python Scripting: Assign existing geometry node group to newly generate object

Tags: python, scripting, geometry

I'm creating a number of objects in a loop, how can I assign an existing Geometry Node group to these created objects?

I've tried to assign data.node_group.name the name of the group but that just renames the existing group!

```
import bpy

for i in range(1):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, location=(i*2, i*2, 0))
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1,1,1))
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='NODES') # This adds the GeometryNodes modifier
    data = bpy.context.object.modifiers.get("GeometryNodes")

# Assign 'MY GEOMETRY NODE GROUP' to the GeometryNodes modifier
#    data.node_group.name = "MY GEOMETRY NODE GROUP"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an existing node group using:

```
ng = bpy.data.node_groups['your node group']
```

Adding a Geometry Node modifier:

```
modifier=o.modifiers.new("MyName", "NODES")
```

(where `o` is your object)

The modifier is added, but adding it also creates a new node group that you can delete by:

```
 bpy.data.node_groups.remove(modifier.node_group)
```

Then you can add the 'MY GEOMETRY NODE GROUP' by:

```
modifier.node_group = bpy.data.node_groups['MY GEOMETRY NODE GROUP']
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [modifier_copy_to_selected](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=modifier_copy_to_selected#bpy.ops.object.modifier_copy_to_selected) operator with a [context override](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15118/86891) :

```
object_to_copy_from = bpy.context.active_object
objects_to_copy_to = bpy.context.selected_objects

override = {
    "active_object": object_to_copy_from,
    "selected_objects": objects_to_copy_to
    }

bpy.ops.object.modifier_copy_to_selected(override, modifier="GeometryNodes")
```