# Applying specific Geometry Nodes modifier to an object with python

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, geometry-nodes, add-on

I am very new to python and writing blender addons. I am currently trying to make an addon that takes the selected object, makes a new cube at that location, and then applies a set of custom geo nodes to that object.

Assuming the geo node groups I want to apply have already been appended to the file, how can I specify to Blender what geo node group I want it to apply with python? I have tried learning through the info dialogue, and it hasn't given me much to work off of.

Comment: Hi. Does this answered question help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/243750/python-scripting-assign-existing-geometry-node-group-to-newly-generate-object

Comment: Hello, michael, it does sound as if the linked answers should answer your question, so it's fair to call this a duplicate. Of course, if they don't, edit this post to explain why, and we'll re-open it for you