# How to add several images to video sequencer at once for slideshow?

Tags: python, interface, video-sequence-editor

I've got a few dozen photos, and I would like to add them to the VSE all at once, to make a slideshow. Normally, this turns them into a stop-motion-like sequence, but I still want the photos to be individual strips, about 3-5 seconds long. Is there an easy way to do this, via the UI or scripting? I could go digging in the Python docs, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It would be easy enough to write a script, but it might take as long to debug it as to do the whole thing once.  There are programs just for putting slide shows together.  Would one of them be better?

Comment: @MartyFouts I’ve been trying to find one that can do what I want, but so far it’s been rather difficult. I need to be able to add custom music, arrange and remove photos after they’re added, and hopefully do image transforms (IE the photo is sideways and I fix it). I’m finally resorting to an archived windows essentials package.

Comment: It looks like you would load the images using [image operators](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.image.html) and then use [bpy.ops.sequencer.image_strip_add](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254903/align-active-camera-to-view-using-python/254906#254906) to create an image strip but I don't have time to workout the details just now

Comment: @MartyFouts I’ll take a look. Thanks. It looks like the later link has the wrong address, though.

Comment: It certainly did.  Sorry.  Had the wrong url on the clipboard.  Try [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.sequencer.html#bpy.ops.sequencer.image_strip_add)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, after adding an image sequence, one can break it up into individual images with Strip -> Separate Images [Y], and then enter how many frames each image should last. Scaling is another problem for now, since Image -> Apply -> Scale to fit seems to be only working for one image at a time, but this is a first step.