# Align camera to view

Tags: python, camera

I have a script that creates new camera and make it active
but i cant override context for 'align camera to view'.

How to do it in blender 3.6?

```
import bpy

# Create a new camera
bpy.ops.object.camera_add()

# Get the newly created camera object
new_camera = bpy.context.object

# Set the new camera as the active camera
bpy.context.scene.camera = new_camera
```

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15118/how-do-i-override-context-for-bpy-ops-mesh-loopcut

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much about python

Maybe this:

```
import bpy

# Create a new camera
bpy.ops.object.camera_add()

# Get the newly created camera object
new_camera = bpy.context.object

# Set the new camera as the active camera
bpy.context.scene.camera = new_camera

# Align the camera to the current view
bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view()
```

Comment: Thank you for your variant

Comment: Im happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

For your temporary override you will still need to locate a 3d viewport window to use the command.

```
# Blender 3.6.1

import bpy

# Create a new camera
bpy.ops.object.camera_add()

# Get the newly created camera object
new_camera = bpy.context.object

# Set the new camera as the active camera
bpy.context.scene.camera = new_camera

# overrides
win = bpy.context.window
scr = win.screen
areas3d = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
region = [region for region in areas3d[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']

with bpy.context.temp_override(window=win, area=areas3d[0], region=region[0]):
        bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view()
```

Comment: Ratt, thank you a lot!