# What is the proper context for working with material nodes?

Tags: python, node-editor

Trying to work with nodes in a ShaderNodeTree on a material I've just created, and I'm getting the dreaded "context is incorrect" error.

Here's some code I successfully ran in the Blender UI:

```
def test():
    C.window.workspace = D.workspaces['Shading']
    new_material = D.materials.new('color_ramp')
    new_material.use_nodes = True
    C.active_object.data.materials.append(new_material)
    C.window.screen.areas[3].type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    C.window.screen.areas[3].ui_type = 'ShaderNodeTree'
    spaces = C.window.screen.areas[3].spaces
    return spaces[0]
```

With an object selected, this correctly switches the window, creates a new material, assigns it to the object, switches the area to the Node Editor, and even has the main node selected in the Node Editor area. Calling `data = test()` and then calling `data` returns:

`bpy.data.screens['Scripting']...SpaceNodeEditor`

and does not allow me to deselect the main node, nor does it allow me to add new nodes. From the code of the `poll()` function for nodes/node trees, I was able to see the context needs to be in the Node Editor and have a node tree selected. Calling `data.node_tree` in the UI correctly prints the node_tree, but interestingly enough my program I'm building does not.

Does anyone know the correct context for working with nodes/node trees?

EDIT: I added some print statements to the function to see if I could see what was going wrong with the context. Looks like it isn't changing the Workspace properly, which could I suppose be part of the issue? Even though it's in the Node Editor area...I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I recently posted regarding `context.temp_override` [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299810/align-camera-to-view#comment517984_299810) but you will need to adjust for the shading area

Comment: you can read more about context override in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add and use `NODE_EDITOR` as the area type when overriding. for example you can easily deselect the nodes using [this code](https://pastebin.com/PGTQTbKT)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I'm getting a StopIteration error when I run that code, unfortunately. I know I need to do a temp_override, I just can't get the context correct. It seems to be ignoring me trying to set the proper context.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/X4l3UA9

Comment: @DevinGardner because one of the areas need to be the shader node open.

Comment: Calling `bpy.context.window.screen.areas[3].type = 'NODE_EDITOR'` and changing one of the areas to the Node Editor still does not allow it to run properly.

Comment: This first test: https://pastebin.com/ktCmPd4g is what I'm running. This is the output: https://pastebin.com/4JrCvG9d

Comment: @DevinGardner your code works fine on Blender 3.6 as long as one area is open with shader editor :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148197/discussion-between-harry-mckenzie-and-devin-gardner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar issue with [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267380/why-does-nw-add-textures-for-principled-work-w-existing-material-but-not-w-d) that has the same [unintuitive solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/268511/142292):

```
area.spaces.active.node_tree = nodes #add this line before the ops statement
bpy.ops.node.select(deselect_all=True)
```